# How to dispatch an application in a new process?

Tags: c#

How to dispatch an application in a new process in C#?

I need to do the same thing as some python code where they have:

```
myApp = Dispatch(MAPPOINT)
```

What is the equivalent to that in C#? What that does is it starts a new process
for the application MAPPOINT.

Thanks

Comment: you have what you're looking for in your Title the key word there is `Process` do a search on how to use the `Process` Class Many examples are on this current page if you look at the `Related Section` also google how to use ` Process.Start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `Process.Start`?

```
Process.Start("notepad");
```